# No dynamic binding when abstract type involved in Scala?

Tags: scala, dynamic-binding, abstract-type

When I was trying the Animal/Food example for abstract types in Martin Odersky's *Programming in Scala*,

```
class Food
abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food:SuitableFood)
}
class Grass extends Food
class Cow extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood=Grass
  override def eat(food:SuitableFood) {}
}
val bessy:Animal = new Cow
bessy.eat(new Grass)
```

I got the following error:

```
scala> <console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Grass
 required: bessy.SuitableFood
                  bessy.eat(new Grass)
                            ^
```

The original example by Martin was `bessy.eat(new Fish)`, which would definitely fail, but I didn't expect it'd fail for `Grass` as well. The above error can be avoided by letting `bessy` be `Cow` instead of `Animal`: `val bessy:Cow = new Cow`.

Does this mean dynamic binding doesn't work here?

**Edited:** 
Simple dynamic binding for regular inheritance in Scala:

```
abstract class Parent {
  def sig:String = "Parent"
}
class Child extends Parent {
  override def sig:String = "Child"
}
```

And I had this, where `x:Parent` gave *Child* as well:

```
scala> new Child().sig
res1: String = Child

val x:Parent = new Child()
x: Parent = Child@3a460b07

x.sig
res2: String = Child
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala is statically typed.  An arbitrary animal cannot eat grass, and you have just tried to feed grass to an arbitrary animal.  It happens to be a cow, but you have stated (with `: Animal`) that the compiler may only assume that it is an animal.

If you allow the compiler to know that `bessy` is a `Cow` (`val bessy = new Cow`), then she'll eat grass just fine.

Comment: Well, am I taking the dynamic binding concept wrong? `List` in Java has `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`, so when you call a `xs.get(idx)` on a `List`, you get the `ArrayList` version when it's an `ArrayList` implementation. I didn't expect Scala would deviate from this.

Comment: @lcn - Types must match.  Your "simple" example has the same type signature for `Parent.sig` and `Child.sig`.  Inheritance (of the "dynamic binding" type in C++) works just fine, but you must obey the types you've given.

Comment: so you mean when abstract type involved, the `eat` methods will have *different* signatures and thus are different methods? I understand this suits better for the purpose of abstract types, but it should really be documented that there is *NO* dynamic binding here.

Comment: @lcn - It is dynamic binding (as the term is used in C++; this means different things in other contexts) at runtime, as the appropriate method is selected from the method table.  However, at compile-time, the compiler will stop you from feeding grass to an arbitrary animal.